# How do I delete a profile not found in the registry?

Tags: powershell, profile

Hello I'm trying to delete old user profiles with powershell. I have been able to successfully delete profiles when they are found in the registry with the following script.

```
$localProfilePath = "C:\\Users\\$User"
$WMIQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_UserProfile WHERE localpath = '$localProfilePath'"
$profile = Get-WmiObject -Query $WMIQuery -ComputerName $Computer_Name 
Remove-WmiObject -InputObject $profile
```

When I try to delete profiles that are not found in the registry I get the following error.

> ```
> Remove-WmiObject : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
> ```

I have found that several older profiles are not found in the registry for some reason. It may be because of a update. I tried using other methods but keep getting errors when I try to delete the profile. I think that windows is blocking the hidden files from being deleted in a profile. Does anyone know how to fix this issue or know a better way of doing it?

Comment: Use `net users /delete <name>` to remove users, unfortunately, this doesn't remove their folders so you can just use `rd /s C:\Users\<name>`. Run as administrator

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).